# Android - What do i need to perform a service in the background

Tags: android, service, background, broadcastreceiver

I currently have a service setup that emails a bunch of files. What I want to do is add a scheduling system setup so that at a certain time each night, that service runs (those emails are sent).

I thought maybe a Broadcast Receiver triggered by an AlarmManager would work, and it does except it only runs when the app is running. I read that Broadcast Receivers only run in the UI thread. I need this to work regardless if the app is running or not.

Im going to assume that what I need is a broadcast receiver to start [blank] to run in the background and when the AlarmManager sends an alarm that [blank] will start the service I already have setup.

If that is the correct procedure, what is [blank] ? If its not the correct procedure then what is ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to run a RemoteService (http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/09/android-developer-tutorial-part-9.html), and this article explains how to use the `AlarmManager` to start up a Service.

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html

I actually made this change today, and my program is working better at work.

The RemoteService is so that the Service doesn't die when your Activity dies, basically.

Comment: That definitely seems to be the problem with my current setup, is that when the app is not active, the service never starts. This could be the thing i was looking for. Thanks! I'll start making the changes sometime tn

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure is correct,if you don't need an IPC ,then no necessary to implement a remote service.

Comment: then, local or remote service?